# Setting object in IE 9 "Object doesn't support this action"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Trying to set a attribute of an object to a new object and IE 9 gives me a strange error 
"Object Doesn't support this action" I dont understand why this is the only browser that complains.

http://jsfiddle.net/billpull/QNm6f/1/

I wrote the code in the order it gets parsed in wondering if that is the issue because technically the browser would reach this part before the object exists but when the code is actually executed it does exist.

```
var project = {};

project.viewModels = {};

project.myViewLocator = {
    viewOne: null,
    viewTwo: null
};

$(function () {
   project.myViewLocator.viewOne = new project.viewModels.ViewOneModel(); 
});

project.viewModels.ViewOneModel = function () {
  // some logic  
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jsFiddle has this ordering issue because you have it set for `onload` in the left panel.  That means that when you call:

```
$(function () {
   project.myViewLocator.viewOne = new project.viewModels.ViewOneModel(); 
});
```

the document is already loaded so it executes the callback immediately and thus `ViewOneModel()` is not yet defined.

If you change the left panel to be "No wrap in `<body>`", then the ordering issue goes away because the document is not yet ready and the callback function is not called until after the contructor function has been defined.

If you see differences in this timing between browsers, that is probably due to the different ways that jQuery implements the DOMReady method in different browsers.  But, in all cases, waiting to run the code until `onload` has fired will mean that the DOM is already ready and DOMReady code may have already fired or may fire immediately when registered.

---

The simplest recommendation would be to define any function before it is used and not have to worry about timing issues like this.

---

Further info:  In tracing through the jQuery implement for `.ready()` (or the form you are using), you can find this block of code:

```
// Do we need to add the callbacks to the
// current firing batch?
if ( firing ) {
    firingLength = list.length;
    // With memory, if we're not firing then
    // we should call right away
} else if ( memory ) {
    firingStart = start;
    fire( memory );
}
```

which shows (you can just read the comments) that if the DOM is already ready, jQuery calls the callback immediately when you register it.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the `dom ready` callback to initialize `ViewOneModel` *before* you defined it. I guess IE9 is executing the callback *before* the definition, because the DOM is already ready.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that $() is an async method.
However, when in fact, if the dom is ready before calling it, it's a false assumptions.

Changing the order will work:

```
var project = {};

project.viewModels = {};

project.myViewLocator = {
    viewOne: null,
    viewTwo: null
};

project.viewModels.ViewOneModel = function () {
  // some logic  
};

$(function () {
   project.myViewLocator.viewOne = new project.viewModels.ViewOneModel(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work fine, the issue is you are calling a function on an object before it gets defined.

Here is the [jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNm6f/4/)

```
var project = {};

project.viewModels = {};

project.myViewLocator = {
    viewOne: null,
    viewTwo: null
};
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function () {
   project.myViewLocator.viewOne = new project.viewModels.ViewOneModel(); 
});

project.viewModels.ViewOneModel = function () {
  // some logic  
    alert('it s working fine ...');
};

})
```